# Rails Storing data in two table in one text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= f.text_field :invoice_amnt, :short_over, class: "form-control",placeholder: "Enter Invoice Amount", :required=> true, data: {autonumeric: true}  %>
```

I want my textfield to have :invoice_amnt and short_over at the same time but the one I am doing cannot have 2 arguments.

Comment: How can it represent two variables? I think you need to re-examine your design. Which value would it display if both variables have values?

Comment: Please attach a static screenshot of the form, you want to build.